# Google Maps iOS rendering empty tiles white instead of clear

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm making an app that uses Tile Layers in Google Maps to provide custom indoor maps for buildings of interest. I've got the tile layer sending tiles at the appropriate coordinates, but any time one of the tiles is empty, Google Maps is rendering it as white, not transparent. You can see this in the attached screenshot.

[image]

What is going on here and how can I get it to render those tiles as transparent? Note, the tiles exhibit no unusual characteristics when viewed in Photoshop or Preview.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was: ImageMagick was saving the fully-transparent tiles in a 16-bit format (8 gray / 8 alpha) that Google Maps didn't understand. Tiles with content were being saved as the usual 32-bit RGBA format. I added the following option to my tile generating script to fix it:

```
-define png:color-type=6
```